# Exim redirect error messages

Tags: linux, email-server, email

With the File "/etc/cpanel_exim_system_filter" how do i make it so all error messages go to webmaster@example.com?

I originally had a script made in cpanel which says the following

```
if
 error_message 
then
 save "/....../example.com/webmaster/" 660
endif
```

this correctly saved any error messages to the webmaster mailbox.

however it just moved the files there, so the original recipient did not receive an error message saying how,why and what time their email did not arrive at its destination.

so basically I need something which does the same thing, except it copies the file instead of moving it, with only the error message going to the webmaster mailbox, not the email sent which did not arrive.

how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
if
 error_message 
then
 deliver $h_to
 save "/....../example.com/webmaster/" 660
endif
```

It should deliver a copy of the message, and save a copy locally.